# How to capture text in first line of current screen in Android?

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-layout, webview

My projec is a e-book reader application. There is only a VebView in screen and getting data from html file. It has only text content. I need to do get text in first line of current screen. In next step, I need to find the text in document and getting the text's position of screen. Finally, I need to scroll the found position. All of things necessary to solve that problem: ([WebView Text Zoom Issue in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36235903/webview-text-zoom-issue-in-android))

html content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <head>
        <style type="text/css"> 
            p{} p.x1{} p.x2{} p.x3{} p.x4{} 
            h2.x1{} h2.x2{} h2.x3{} h2.x4{}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        //paragraph-1
        <p class="x1">Title-1</p>
        <p class="x2">Title-2</p>
        <p class="x3">Title-3</p>
        <p class="x4">Title-4</p>
        <p>Text content.</p>


        //paragraph-2
        <h class="x1">Title-1</p>
        <h class="x2">Title-2</p>
        <p>Text content.</p>


        //paragraph-3
        <h class="x3">Title-1</p>
        <h class="x4">Title-2</p>
        <p class="x3">Title-3</p>
        <p>Text content.</p>


        //paragraph-4
        <h class="x2">Title-1</p>
        <p class="x3">Title-2</p>
        <p>Text content.</p>


        //...

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: if you dont need to render it, then why use a WebView? Just make a raw HTTP(S) request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are searching for this?

```
function findTopObject (elements) {
    var top = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    var obj = null;

    Array.from(elements).forEach(function (o) {
        var t = o.getBoundingClientRect(o).top;
        if (t > 0.0 && top > t) {
            obj = o;
            top = t;
        }
    });

    return obj;
}
```

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  p.innerText = "Line " + i;
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}

var elements = document.querySelectorAll("p");
var obj = null;

window.onscroll = function() {
  if (obj != null) {
    obj.style.backgroundColor = "";
  }

  obj = findTopObject(elements);

  if (obj != null) {
    obj.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
};

function findTopObject(elements) {
  var top = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
  var obj = null;
  Array.from(elements).forEach(function(o) {
    var t = o.getBoundingClientRect(o).top;
    if (t > 0.0 && top > t) {
      obj = o;
      top = t;
    }
  });
  return obj;
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to do what you want, 
First get html content by doing

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

String html = "";
InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    str.append(line);
}
in.close();
html = str.toString();
```

Then use sub string conccept to get what you want, have look [Get Html content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2425764/5955593)

Or you can use [Jsoap parser](http://jsoup.org/)
to get value from specified tag in HTML

```
Document doc=Jsoup.connect("http://www.yahoo.com").get();
Elements elements=doc.select("img");

for(Element e:elements)
 {
  System.out.println(e.attr("src"));
 }
```

Comment: html file has many <p>...</p> tags mixed. I don't want to all, I want to only get first row in current screen

Comment: can you show us your html source ? we can figure out what you want ?